# Pandas, concat Series to DF as rows

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, series

I attempting to add a Series to an empty DataFrame and can not find an answer
either in the Doc's or other questions.  Since you can append two DataFrames by row
or by column it would seem there must be an "axis marker" missing from a Series.  Can
anyone explain why this does not work?.

```
import Pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
s1 = pd.Series(['a',5,6])
df1 = pd.concat([df1,s1],axis = 1)
#go run some process return s2, s3, sn ...
s2 = pd.Series(['b',8,9])
df1 = pd.concat([df1,s2],axis = 1)
s3 = pd.Series(['c',10,11])
df1 = pd.concat([df1,s3],axis = 1)
```

> If my example above is some how misleading perhaps using the example from the docs will help.
>
> Quoting:  Appending rows to a DataFrame.
>   While not especially efficient (since a new object must be created), you can append a
>   single row to a DataFrame by passing a Series or dict to append, which returns a new DataFrame as above.  End Quote.
>
> The example from the docs appends "S", which is a row from a DataFrame, "S1" is a Series
>   and attempting to append "S1" produces an error.  My question is WHY will appending "S1  not work?  The assumption behind the question is that a DataFrame must code or contain axes information for two axes, where a Series must contain only information for one axes.
>
> ```
> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
> s = df.xs(3); #third row of DataFrame
> s1 = pd.Series([np.random.randn(4)]); #new Series of equal len
> df= df.append(s, ignore_index=True)
> ```

Result

```
   0  1

0  a  b

1  5  8

2  6  9
```

Desired

```
   0  1 2

0  a  5 6

1  b  8 9
```

Answer (score 17):

You were close, just transposed the result from `concat`

```
In [14]: s1
Out[14]: 
0    a
1    5
2    6
dtype: object

In [15]: s2
Out[15]: 
0    b
1    8
2    9
dtype: object

In [16]: pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).T
Out[16]: 
   0  1  2
0  a  5  6
1  b  8  9

[2 rows x 3 columns]
```

You also don't need to create the empty `DataFrame`.

Comment: Tom, Using your answer, if I now want to concat another Series to the result I get: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_data'

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the third Series you want to concat? If you have it at the same time as `s1` and `s2`, you can do `pd.concat([s1, s2, s3], axis=1).T

Comment: Please see the edited version of the problem, the concat operations do not happen at the same time.

Comment: It's still not clear what your 3rd Series is. And again, you don't need to make an empty DataFrame. Once you have the DataFrame from my answer, you can add additional rows/columns with `.loc[2, :]` or `append` or `join`, take a look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html).

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there no way to call pd.concat in a way that the transpose is not needed?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without losing the dtypes with transpose?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin use pandas.DataFrame constructor instead, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69810437/1280629

Comment: @jcdude Thank you. As time has passed, I see that my question in the comment didn't make sense. If I want to concatenate series to a dataframe as rows, I can't "lose the dtypes" - each series had one dtype, not a different type per item...

Answer (score 12):

The best way is to use DataFrame to construct a DF from a sequence of Series, rather than using concat:

```py
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series(['a',5,6])
s2 = pd.Series(['b',8,9])
pd.DataFrame([s1, s2])
```

Output:

```py
In [4]: pd.DataFrame([s1, s2])
Out[4]: 
   0  1  2
0  a  5  6
1  b  8  9
```

Comment: Yes! So simple. Also works when giving names to the series with `pd.Series(['a',5,6], index = ['char','num_1','num2']) to get column names. And `pd.Series(['a',5,6], index = ['char','num_1','num2'], name='a_5_6')` to get row names.

Answer (score 0):

> A method of accomplishing the same objective as appending a Series to a DataFrame
>   is to just convert the data to an array of lists and append the array(s) to the DataFrame.

data as an array of lists

> def get_example(idx):
>
> > ```
> >    list1 = (idx+1,idx+2 ,chr(idx + 97))
> >    data = [list1]
> >    return(data)
> > ```
>
> df1 = pd.DataFrame()
>
> for idx in range(4):
>
> > ```
> >    data = get_example(idx)
> >    df1= df1.append(data, ignore_index = True)
> > ```

Comment: Append is deprecated since version 1.4.0